# One to many network graph

Tags: gephi

I have a dataset of teachers and students. Each teacher is related to 4 or 5 students but there is no relationship between teachers. I made a nodes and edges file (CSV).

I want to make a network graph in circular format where  teachers are along the circumference and students in the center of the circle. And relationship is shown by lines/edges from teachers to students. How to do that in Gephi? I am completely clueless.

Nodes : `T1,T2,S1,S2,S3,S4,S5` (T stands for teacher and S for student)

Edges : `T1-S1,T1-S3,T1-S4,T2-S1,T2-S5,T2-S4`

Comment: This is not possible with Gephi AFAIK

Comment: @Yannis P. any other tool/method that would work like Tableau, networkx etc ? I am not comfortable with JavaScript so I can't go for D3.js

Comment: Now that I am reflecting a bit, this could work in Gephi, too, by filtering the teacher nodes, run `Circular layout` with a large diameter, then filter only student nodes and run the same layout with smaller diameter. I think you can do the same thing with networkx as well. By running [circular layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout.html)
 on subgraphs